# How to show count of products with category using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am displaying category + product count with this code:

```
SELECT 
    c.category_name, COUNT(p.category_id) AS product_count 
FROM 
    categories AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    products AS p ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE 
    c.sub_category_id = '@variable' 
GROUP BY 
    c.category_name
```

The result is like that:

```
Category_1 (0)
Category_2 (0)
```

Because when you can click the category your products in sub category. It means products have sub_category_id in database not the main category_id.

```
  Sub_Category_1 (20)
  Sub_Category_2 (5)
```

**Categories** table:

```
category_id, category_name,   sub_category_id
---------------------------------------------
1            Category_1             0
2            Category_2             0
3            Sub_Category_1         1   >> Category_1
4            Sub_Category_2         2   >> Category_2  
5            Sub_Category_1_Sub     3   >> Sub_Category_1
6            Sub_Category_2_Sub     4   >> Sub_Category_2
```

**Products** table:

```
product_id  category_id
------------------------    
1             3
2             4
3             3
4             4
5             5
6             6
```

I would like to show total count of products **on main category**.

Because as you see Category_1 and Category_2 returns (0)

Any ideas?

Expected Result:

```
Categories (30)
  Sub Categories_1(15)
    Sub_Categories_Sub_1(10)
    Sub_Categories_Sub_2(5)
  Sub Categories_2(15) 
    Sub_Categories_Sub_1(2)
    Sub_Categories_Sub_2(8)
    Sub_Categories_Sub_2(5)
```

**UPDATED** 18.08.2019 - 17:15

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @forpas i think it's clear with my query. Category table have category_name, category_id and sub_category_id. Product table is only have category_id for relation. Let's think about computer parts selling. You're listing category of storage units.you have sub categories like usb, harddisk etc. with counts but you can not show total storage units of counts with this query.

Comment: _show total count of products on main category_ Think about what you wrote. The concept of subcategory is irrelevant here unless there is some detail you left out.

Comment: @Mert *i think it's clear with my query* Nothing is clear in your query. Even after you posted sample data you wan this to work for subcategories of subcategories invalidating the answers you already have. This is why I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get all the sub categories related to the specific category. To do that, you use a recursive cte.
Then, you use a left join between that recursive cte and the products table, counting the products group by the root category.
Here's a code example:

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Categories AS TABLE
(
    category_id int, 
    category_name varchar(50),   
    sub_category_id int
)
INSERT INTO @Categories (category_id, category_name, sub_category_id) VALUES
(1, 'Category_1'        , 0),
(2, 'Category_2'        , 0),
(3, 'Sub_Category_1'    , 1),
(4, 'Sub_Category_2'    , 2),
(5, 'Sub_Category_1_Sub', 3),
(6, 'Sub_Category_2_Sub', 4);

DECLARE @Products AS TABLE
(
    product_id  int,
    category_id int
)

-- comments to make it clear which product belongs which main category
INSERT INTO @Products (product_id, category_id) VALUES
(1, 3), -- Category_1
(2, 4), -- Category_2
(3, 3), -- Category_1
(4, 4), -- Category_2
(5, 5), -- Category_1
(6, 5); -- Category_1
```

Then, the recursive cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT category_id, category_name, sub_category_id, category_name As MainCategoryName
    FROM @Categories 
    WHERE sub_category_id = 0
    -- If you want to start from a particular subCategory you can change the where condition:
    -- for instance, `where category_id = 3` will count the products the belongs to Sub_Category_1 and Sub_Category_1_Sub
    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.category_id, T.category_name, T.sub_category_id, MainCategoryName
    FROM @Categories AS T
    JOIN CTE
        ON T.sub_category_id = CTE.category_id
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT MainCategoryName As CategoryName, COUNT(P.product_id) As NumberOfProducts
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN @Products As P
    ON P.category_id = CTE.category_id 
GROUP BY MainCategoryName
```

Results:

```
CategoryName    NumberOfProducts
Category_1      4
Category_2      2
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/QKG4400)

Comment: Thanks, i hope it will help others too.

Comment: I have one little question for you. Can we add more results to query? When i try getting Column CTE.column is invalid because of group by.

Comment: You can add more columns but that will force you to change the group by clause as well. Another option would be to not use `group by` at all and replace it with an `over` clause with partition by `MainCategoryName`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want ?

You just want to add category_id in your group by and have a count then as below

```
   SELECT category_id ,c.category_name, 
  count(*) AS product_count FROM 
     categories AS c
     LEFT JOIN products AS p ON
  p.category_id = c.category_id
  WHERE c.sub_category_id='@variable' 
     GROUP BY category_id, 
     c.category_name
```

Comment: thanks for interesting and trying to help. solution is marked.